# CICS Return VS GOBACK

Tags: cobol, mainframe, cics

What happened to the Commarea passed by Program A in both of these examples?

Program A does an EXEC CICS LINK to Program B then Program B uses the GOBACK command

Program A does an EXEC CICS LINK to Program B then Program B uses the EXEC CICS RETURN command

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the whole linkage section return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054806/does-the-whole-linkage-section-return)

Comment: I feel that you have some problem relating to these questions. Perhaps just ask straight out, if you can't get to the answer through this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28056695/1927206.

Nothing happens to the commarea.

If B changes it, it is changing the storage that A is aware of.

Only the address of data is "passed" between programs. Only the original data exists, Program B manipulates the original data. There is no copying of data between CALLing and CALLed programs.

Separate from what happens to the data (nothing) the two examples you show have identical behaviour. Use the local standards for your site.

Comment: Bill, would you say that this question is a duplicate of the one you linked?

Comment: @JohnSaunders The same answer would serve for both, as far as the question here is asked. The only difference is in something shown, but not asked. I'd say Yes, then.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'll make the answer a comment in the morning, and delete the answer, so that the auto-removal of no-answer closed questions will operate (unless OP puts more into the question).

Answer (score 0):

GOBACK is an older COBOL construct used in the called program.
EXEC CICS RETURN gives up control to CICS. CICS determines what program gets control next.